# Add a project global variable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

in my main html file I have defined the following which I want to be a project global variable :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var path='/';
    path=path.substr(0, path.length - 1);
</script>
```

I am then using the variable path in several different ts files and **it works fine**.
However, I do get a compilation warning saying that path is not defined. How can I prevent this warning from happening ?

Comment: Declare it on `globals.d.ts` file? https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/globals.html

Comment: @PauloBu Where do I put that file? Do I need any other configuration to make it work? I've tried making the declaration in `globals.d.ts` in my baseUrl, and it's not picking it up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a `something.d.ts` file (`.d.ts` is the file extension for type declarataion) and make sure that it's included or not excluded in your `tsconfig.json`:

**something.d.ts**

```
declare var path: string;
```

Comment: Can you expand on "make sure it's included"? I've created the declaration file and included it under `"files": [ ... ]` in tsconfig, but TypeScript still can't find the name. Do I need to include the declaration file in all my source files? What's the point of making it global then?

Comment: Let's sat that we have created a `global-types.d.ts` located at `my-project/src/global-types.d.ts`.

To include that file ensure that `tsconfig.json` (it lives in project root) has a `"include": [ "src" ]`.

The path inside `include` must be relative to `tsconfig.json`location, and must points to a parent folder of your `global-types.d.ts`. 

Make sure that you had not excluded the file path inside `"exclude": [ '...' ]` in `tsconfig.json`.